# An ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$ and monotone sequences

Tags: real-analysis, filters

Let $a$ be a nontrivial ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$ having limit point $0$.

I propose the following conjecture to solve:

**Conjecture** Either every set $A\in a$ is dense at some interval or there exists a strictly increasing sequence $z$ such that $\operatorname{im} z\in a$ or there exists a strictly decreasing sequence $z$ such that $\operatorname{im} z\in a$.

The basis I feel it may be true is the following: points of a set in $a$ is either the image of a monotone sequence (as if $a$ contains image of the sequence) or not. If it is not, then it appears to be "dense" near $0$ and thus probably dense in some interval near zero. I cannot give more exact reasons why I feel it may be true.

I hope positive solution of this conjecture may allow me to prove or disprove $|\mathbb{R}|_{\geq} = |\mathbb{R}| \sqcap \geq$. I cannot explain what it means, see http://mathematics21.org/binaries/addons.pdf draft

Comment: I've corrected the "dense" condition.

Comment: I've again corrected the question formulation

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Isn't it obvious that the question is to prove or disprove the conjecture?

Comment: You have been a user of this site for a while now, and you should have already noticed that asking questions without any context whatsoever is not particularly appreciated. Whose conjecture is this? I conjecture it is yours — and then: what possible basis do you have to believe this is true? In what context does this arise? You can surely provide *some* kind of information to make it clear that the statement was not generated by a Markov chain trained with a few textbooks on set theory, for example.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It is my conjecture. The basis I feel it may be true is the following: points of a set in $a$ is either the image of a monotone sequence (as if $a$ contains image of the sequence) or not. If it is not, then it appears to be "dense" near $0$ and thus probably dense in some interval near zero. I cannot give more exact reasons why I feel it may be true. I hope positive solution of this conjecture may allow me to prove or disprove $|\mathbb{R}|_{\geq}=|\mathbb{R}| \sqcap \geq$. I cannot explain what it means, see http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/addons.pdf draft

Comment: Add whatever useful information there is to the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is *not true*.

The image of any sequence of reals, monotonic or not, is countable; so letting $\mathcal{C}$ be the *cocountable filter* on $\mathbb{R}$, we have that any ultrafilter extending $\mathcal{C}$ doesn't contain the image of a sequence of reals.

Now consider $\mathcal{C}\cup\{C\}$, where $C$ is the Cantor set. $C$ is 
 of course nowhere dense, but since it is uncountable we also have that $\mathcal{C}\cup\{C\}$ has the finite intersection property. So there is some ultrafilter $\mathfrak{U}\supseteq\mathcal{C}\cup\{C\}$, and this ultrafilter is a counterexample to your conjecture.

---

In fact, we can do better, and by a similar argument get an ultrafilter containing the Cantor set which doesn't contain *any closed set of bounded Cantor-Bendixson rank* (note that such an ultrafilter can't be principal, so it also won't contain any closed set of bounded Cantor-Bendixson rank *minus finitely many points*, e.g. the image of a sequence). This is because the union of finitely many closed sets of bounded Cantor-Bendixson rank is again a closed set of bounded Cantor-Bendixson rank, and hence can't cover the Cantor set. (No need to bring the Baire category theorem into play, although it is an extension of this idea.)

---

Another example which contradicts a reasonable intuition is that there is an ultrafilter on $\omega$ such that every set in the ultrafilter has positive upper density. (Note that such an ultrafilter can never be Ramsey.) This "reasonable intuition" is, I think, similar to the intuition behind your conjecture, which is why I mention it.